# The Python Workbook: Exercise 69 - Approximate pi

Tags: python, pi

I'm a new learner of Python and currently doing the Python Workbook by Ben Stephenson. I'm stuck with exercise 69 and my pi value is diverging.... can anyone help? Any errors with my code?

I've also attached the exercise question here. [Exercise Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQe5b.png)

```
#Exercise 69: Approximate pi

maxrun = 15
denominator1 = 2
denominator2 = 3
denominator3 = 4
fractionpos = (4/(denominator1*denominator2*denominator3))
denominatora = 4
denominatorb = 5
denominatorc = 6
fractionneg = -4/(denominatora*denominatorb*denominatorc)

pi = 3
count = 1

while maxrun != 0:
    if count %2 != 0:   #odd runs are positive
        pi = pi+fractionpos
        print('Approximation',count,'pi value is',pi)
        count = count+1
        denominator1 = denominator1+4
        denominator2 = denominator2+4
        denominator3 = denominator3+4
        maxrun = maxrun-1
    elif count %2 ==0:    #even runs are negative
        pi = pi+fractionneg
        print('Approximation',count,'pi value',pi)
        count = count+1
        denominatora = denominator1+4
        denominatorb = denominator2+4
        denominatorc = denominator3+4
        maxrun = maxrun-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you update your denominators, you'll need to also update your fraction.
Right now your `fractionpos` and `fractioneg` are not changing and so each iteration, you are adding the original terms. This is why your pi approximation diverges.

We can ammend this by updating `fractionpos` and `fractionneg` after updating our denominators.

```
if count %2 != 0:   #odd runs are positive
    pi = pi+fractionpos
    print('Approximation',count,'pi value is',pi)
    count = count+1
    denominator1 = denominator1+4
    denominator2 = denominator2+4
    denominator3 = denominator3+4
    fractionpos = (4/(denominator1*denominator2*denominator3))
    maxrun = maxrun-1
else:    #even runs are negative
    pi = pi+fractionneg
    print('Approximation',count,'pi value',pi)
    count = count+1
    denominatora = denominator1+4
    denominatorb = denominator2+4
    denominatorc = denominator3+4
    fractionneg = -4/(denominatora*denominatorb*denominatorc)
    maxrun = maxrun-1
```

Comment: Amazing!! I didn;t know I have to update my fractionpos and fractionneg, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in this code.

First, when you do the negative part of the fraction, you should be adding 4 to denominatora,b,c instead of 1,2,3.

Second, `fractionpos` and `fractionneg` are only calculated once. You need to recalculate them every iteration.

Also, you can get rid of denominatora,b,c and just use 1,2,3 for both if you are only adding two each loop. If you want a bit more of a challenge, you can do it with a single denominator variable instead of three

Since you are learning Python and this is an exercise for you, I recommend you not just copy the code below, and instead make the changes yourself. Have fun with Python!

```
    if count %2 != 0:   #odd runs are positive
        pi = pi+(4/(denominator1*denominator2*denominator3))
        print('Approximation',count,'pi value is',pi)
        count = count+1
        denominator1 = denominator1+4
        denominator2 = denominator2+4
        denominator3 = denominator3+4
        maxrun = maxrun-1
    elif count %2 ==0:    #even runs are negative
        pi = pi+-4/(denominatora*denominatorb*denominatorc)
        print('Approximation',count,'pi value',pi)
        count = count+1
        denominatora = denominatora+4
        denominatorb = denominatora+4
        denominatorc = denominatora+4
        maxrun = maxrun-1
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks so much for your help!! Yes denominator123 is supposed to be abc (whoops). I like your suggestion of just adding 2 every loop, I struggled with the alternating positive and negative signs but I might practice some more and try make it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

```
pi = pi+fractionpos # This does not work because its value stays the same.
```

`fractionpos` and `fractionneg` should be updated every time you change the denominators. You can do so by reassigning a value to them in the while-loop.

In your `elif` statement, you should add 4 to `denominatora` instead of `denominator1` and the other ones as well.

```
 elif count %2 ==0:    #even runs are negative
        pi = pi+fractionneg
        print('Approximation',count,'pi value',pi)
        count = count+1
        denominatora = denominator1+4  # This goes wrong and the following as well
        denominatorb = denominator2+4
        denominatorc = denominator3+4
        maxrun = maxrun-1
```

Comment: Ah yes I've updated it now, thanks so much! What a great community!